# Need max marks scored in each subject by a student

Tags: sql, plsqldeveloper

I have three tables ..

```
Student 
Id     Name 
1      vesd
2      Eet

Subject table 
Id   name 
1    Science 
2    maths 

Marks 
Stud_id    Sub_id  Marks 
1             1      20
1             2      30
2             1      40
2             2      50
```

I need the max marks scored in each subject by a student.

Comment: What do you want, what did you try?

Comment: Need max marks scored in each subject  by  a  student .. please help .

Comment: This is very confusing.  Can you provide some sort of table structure with the data?  I can't tell what the table names and fields and data are.  What is "Name 1 vesd 2. Eet?"

Comment: First row is colunm name .. rest is data of that column

Comment: Downvoted for overwriting good edits. Please make sure you use useful and informative titles here, and refrain from "please-help-me" begging.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

`SELECT student.name, subject.name, MAX(mark) 
FROM marks 
INNER JOIN student 
ON marks.student_id = student.id 
INNER JOIN subject 
ON marks.subject_id = subject.id 
GROUP BY student.name,subject.name;`

You can check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcd3d/1

Comment: I need  which student scored maximum marks in each subject

Comment: @shag: if you are going to change your requirements after someone helps you, please at least update the question to be more specific. Remember that vague questions are a good way to waste the time of volunteers, so it pays to be specific.

Comment: Sorry .. I just updated in comment  . So that .you can reply me .  ASAP .. can you please provide the solution for same ..?